# Project won't execute PDF in any PC

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, exe

I have the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Image logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("\\header.jpg");
        logo.ScalePercent(49f);
        logo.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 50, 50);
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("C:\\test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\test.pdf");

        iTextSharp.text.Font general = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Paragraph spc = new Paragraph("\n", general);
        Paragraph pra = new Paragraph("Test   " + textBox1.Text , general);

        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(logo);
        doc.Add(pra);

        doc.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" Please Close The Source File ");
    }
}
```

When i build the project to export an EXE file then install it in another computer , the catch message only shown and no PDF file created , but PDF file created only in my PC .

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is exception that you received

Comment: @karim I am sure u don't have the `header.jpg` in the computer where you are not getting the PDF

Comment: @Nalaka MessageBox.Show(" Please Close The Source File ");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reason for this kind of behavior.. to resolve

1. Make sure you have the `Header.jpg` in the new system
2. Also Make sure you copy `itextsharp.dll` to the new computer with the `exe`

Comment: just i donot understand , if i build my project it not must get all DLL and images required for project ?? if not , Could you guide me with the link to explain this matter ??

Comment: @Karim You are making too many assumptions about the PC of other users. You assume that they have the font `Arial`, you assume that you are allowed to write to the `C:` drive,... You probably aren't even shipping the iTextSharp DLL and the `header.jpg` with your exe. *Could you guid me with a link...* is a strange question. You should get an education on how to build a .NET project.

Comment: @Karim As `Bruno` pointed it out You must learn about building a .NET project.. there is no such link for this particular scenario. Its common  practice  to have your DLLs with you when you create any windows App. bcz the clinte PC will not be having the DLLs your referring to. For the time being. for this issue you have to copy the itextSharp.dll and the header.jpg and put it in the same place where your putting the EXE

Comment: @too_cool Thank you for your help , i will try search and see how can i do it , thanks again :)

Comment: @too_cool your hent guid me with the solution , i added header picture and DLL file to the resources , then i add GetInstance to Itextsharp.Image .
Thanks again too_cool :)